# Code-Completion for FXML in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx-2, code-completion, fxml

Is there a possibility to get code-completion working for FXML(JavaFX 2.2)-files in eclipse?

Greetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[e(fx)clipse](http://www.efxclipse.org/) is still quite new, but it should have all the necessary code editing features. The website explicitly states

> One of the coolest feature of fxgraph is that it integrates with JDT
>   (e.g. you get the JavaDoc for all referenced elements, autocompletion
>   support, ...).

Comment: fxgraph is not fxml, though you are likely right that the e(fx)clipse project also provides code completion for fxml.